# Tipo de dados para latitude e longitude

Tags: mysql, sql, tipagem, geolocalização

Estou trabalhando em um novo projeto onde vou precisar salvar as coordenadas (latitude e longitude) de um endereço no banco de dados.

Existe um tipo de dado ideal para isso?

Pesquisei e vi algumas recomendações de utilizar decimal, mas estou em dúvida se é o melhor tipo para utilizar.

Comment: Quando a base de dados não é especifica para geolocalização, eu uso inteiros mesmo. Por acaso, o range de inteiros do MySQL é suficiente para uma precisão muito boa, e é mais eficiente que qualquer outro formato (exceto se você usar uma tabela específica para formatos geoespaciais, o que costuma ser exagero para aplicações que não vão calcular proximidade com base em geodésicas)

Comment: No meu caso é algo mais simples mesmo. Vou apenas calcular um raio e verificar se determinadas coordenadas estão dentro desse raio. Mas é bom saber que existe um tipo especifico para se trabalhar com isso! :)

Comment: Para medidas de poucos Km de distância, pode usar inteiros numa boa nesse caso, pois trigonometria básica resolve e é muito mais rápido. Para distâncias maiores, o formato geoespacial é necessário, para compensar a curvatura da terra.

Comment: Blz! valeu pela dica! ;)

Comment: Claro que quando falo de usar inteiros, é armazenar o valor multiplicado por uma potência alta de 10, simplesmente para tirar a parte decimal sem perder. Um INT usa 4 bytes, e vai de `-2147483648` a `2147483647`, ou seja, dá para armazenar com 7 casas de precisão se multiplicar por 10^7: `214.7483648` (considerando que só precisa de -180 a 180). Se precisar de mais que isso tem o BIGINT, mas geralmente é um exagero.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Longe disso de usar `decimal` ou qualquer ponto flutuante para valores espaciais.

Não apenas estará usando tipos errados para gravar valores de localização, mas também terá grande perda de performance quando for realizar pesquisas por geo localização.

A muito tempo já se é implementação os tipos `Spatials` nos bancos de dados, seja MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, etc.

Veja aqui sobre [como usar dados espaciais no MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/using-spatial-data.html).

```
CREATE TABLE localizacao (coordenadas GEOMETRY);

INSERT INTO localizacao (coordenadas) VALUES (ST_GeomFromText('POINT(40.71727401 -74.00898606)'));

SELECT ST_AsText(coordenadas) coordenadas FROM localizacao;
```

Comment: como eu faria para saber somente a latitude ou longitude nesse esquema de banco usando GEOMETRY?

Answer (score 8):

Eu costumo usar desta forma e sempre funcionou:

```
lat DECIMAL(10, 8) NOT NULL
lng DECIMAL(11, 8) NOT NULL
```

Considerando:

```
Latitude 40.71727401
Longitude -74.00898606
```

Leia [este artigo](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/problems-with-float.html) que explica como o MySQL funciona dados do tipo ponto flutuante.

> O **dígito de unidade** (um grau decimal) dá a posição em até 111
>   quilômetros (60 milhas náuticas, ou 69 milhas). Ele nos diz em que
>   país aproximadamente estamos.
>
> A **primeira casa decimal** vai até 11,1 km: ela diferencia a posição de
>   uma cidade grande de uma outra cidade grande vizinha.
>
> A **segunda casa decimal** vai até 1,1 km: ela separa uma vila de outra.
>
> A **terceira casa decimal** vai até 110m: ela identifica um campo agrícola
>   enorme ou um campus institucional.
>
> A **quarta cada decimal** vai até 11m: ela identifica uma porção de terra.
>   É comparável à precisão comum de uma unidade de GPS sem nenhuma
>   interferência.
>
> A **quinta casa decimal** vai até 1.1m: ela diferencia uma árvore de
>   outra. A precisão desse nível em GPS comercial só pode ser conseguida
>   com correção diferencial.
>
> A **sexta casa decimal** vale até 0,11 m: você pode ver a estrutura em
>   detalhes, para projetar paisagens ou construir ruas. Ela deve ser mais
>   do que o suficiente para monitorar movimentação de geleiras e rios.
>   Isso só pode ser medido com GPS bem robusto.
>
> A **sétima casa decimal** é no valor de até 11 mm: isso é bom para muita
>   levantamento e está perto do limite do que técnicas baseadas em GPS
>   pode alcançar.
>
> A **oitava casa decimal** é no valor de até 1,1 mm: isso é
>   bom para mapear movimentos das placas e movimentos de vulcões,
>   corrigidos constantemente executando GPS estações base
>   permanente pode ser capaz de atingir esse nível de precisão.

Detalhes

- [Measuring accuracy of latitude and longitude?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/8674)

Comment: Mas no meu caso eu possuo tamanhos de valores diferentes de latitude e longitude dos seus. Por exemplo, em latitude um dos valores é: -23.5598163 e para longitude: -46.60262230000001. Definir um tamanho de casas n ira me causar problemas com tamanhos de coordenadas variados?

Comment: Dê uma olhada [neste link](http://gizmodo.uol.com.br/quao-preciso-e-um-grau-de-longitude-ou-latitude/) onde mostra as precisões relacionadas a latitude e longitude. Essa longitude de  -46.60262230000001, não significa tanto considerando que a sexta casa decimal vale até 0,11 m.

Comment: Entendido! Valeu! ;)