# Qual a melhor maneira armazenar os pontos do Google Maps no banco de dados?

Tags: mysql, google-maps, estrutura-de-dados

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema que vai armazenar alguns trajetos do Google Maps dos usuários cadastrados e estruturei a minha tabela como abaixo:

```
----------------------
| trajetos           |
----------------------
| id                 |
| id_usuario         |
| partida_longitude  |
| partida_latitude   |
| chegada_longitude  |
| chegada_latitude   |
----------------------
```

Esse trajeto será simples e incluirá um ponto de partida e um ponto de chegada.
Sei que essa tabela terá muitos registros (centenas de milhares) e neste momento preciso pensar em desempenho quando for fazer uma busca por algum trajeto.

Minha dúvida é:

> Essa é uma estrutura comum (e talvez a melhor) para armazenar os
>   pontos do Google Maps em um banco de dados?
>
> Outra opção seria armazenar o endereço (ao invés de latitude e
>   longitude), mas isso comprometeria o desempenho ao buscar as
>   informações?
>
> Pensei também em utilizar só o CEP com número do lugar (para
>   precisão), seria melhor que latitude e longitude? Há alguma outra
>   forma de armazenar esses "pontos" que seja eficiente?

Comment: Da forma como está a pergunta, depende de "gosto", ou opinião pessoal. Se puder [edit] e detalhar as necessidades do seu caso específico, o que tentou (ou pensou) e quais as dificuldades encontradas nas alternativas, talvez seja possível uma resposta mais técnica. Quando o tamanho é previsivel dos caminhos eu costumo simplesmente usar um BLOB com as coordenadas empacotadas em "binário" mesmo, pois raramente precisaria de um ponto isolado em um _path_. Se precisar deles individualmente para consultas e/ou metadados, ou muitos pontos simultaneos no mapa pode ser o caso de tabelas geoespaciais

Comment: @Bacco, deixei claro na questão em diversos pontos: "preciso pensar em desempenho", "comprometeria o desempenho", "que seja eficiente", inclusive coloquei várias alternativas que eu pensei em fazer mas não sei qual a melhor nesse quesito. Desempenho não é gosto ou opinião pessoal. O que quer que eu detalhe? / Sim, vi uma pergunta [semelhante](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/157721/tipo-de-dados-para-latitude-e-longitude) que me ajudou muito mas não sei se é a melhor alternativa e como estou utilizando Laravel, vi que não existe uma função "geometry". Talvez sua ideia seja boa.

Comment: Desempenho depende do que você vai fazer com os dados. Separar em linhas aumenta o desempenho de consultas por pontos avulsos e/ou pontos filtrados por regiao da tela (como marcadores diversos), mas piora a organização de paths individuais. Colocar em uma linha só traz um path inteiro numa unica linha de select, deixando muito eficiente o retorno, mas atrapalha o tratamento e setorização de pontos individuais. Cada caso é um caso, e por isso detalhes dão maior chance de respostas que realmente resolvam seu problema. Lembre-se que a sua postagem pode ser reaberta, acho que vale a pena [edit].

Answer (score 1):

Cara existem várias formas de estruturar isso mas tudo depende da necessidade. Eu estruturaria dessa forma:

`id 
 id_usuario 
 origem 
 destino`

Sendo que ficaria **implícito** que os dados das duas colunas **origem** e **destino** estão no formato **latitude** e **longitude**.

Não recomendo usar o endereço ou CEP, porque existem lugares que podem não constar no banco de dados dos Correios e muito menos no do Google Maps. Já com a latitude e longitude você consegue encontrar qualquer lugar do planeta no mapa.

Comment: Realmente, o lance do CEP e endereço tem que ser evitado, mas ainda sim, tudo depende da necessidade.